# Object-oriented database puzzle?

Tags: java, database, oop

I'm currently taking an OOP class and here is my problem:

Assume database for a bike rental: class 'bike' => sub-classes 'borrowed bike' and 'returned bike'. Borrowed bike has the additional field 'due date' and returned bike the field 'location'

The task is to extend this database to treat all kinds of things you could borrow from the rental. However, the implementation needs to be as object-oriented as possible. I have been browsing through my Java book but I haven't been able to find a clever solution.

So, how can I add the functionality that every item (bike, roller skates, ...) is either 'borrowed' or 'returned' with the associated additional fields without having separate sub-classes for every type of item?

(I suggested my teacher that the state of every 'item' is either 'borrowed' or 'returned' but I was told that this is not object-oriented enough)

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Give all "items" (bike, roller skates, etc.) classes the same parent class with that field borrowed/returned.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! I'm sure all these approaches would work in practise. Still I'm not sure what is the most object-oriented way to implement this? My original suggestion was to add the field 'isBorrowed' (or something similar) to class 'Item' but I was told that this is not an object-oriented approach. Using an interface is obliviously OO but in this case I still need to have the fields 'due' and 'location' in class 'Item' which is not optimal. I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface with a `getStatus()` method and make all item classes implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 interfaces for borrowed ones and returned ones.

```
public interface returnedItem(){
   public String getLocation();
   public void setLocation(String s);
}

public interface borrowedItem(){
   public Date getDue();
   public void setDue(Date date);
}
```

Comment: If I use this approach I need to have fields 'due' and 'location' in class 'item', right? This was my original suggestion which was redected by my teacher.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to give all objects (bike, roller skates, etc) a borrowed or returned is to make a super class.

Ex:

```
public class Borrowable {
    private boolean borrowed = false;

    public borrow() {
        borrowed = true;
    }

    public return() {
        borrowed = false;
    } 

    public isBorrowed() {
        return borrowed;
    }

}
```

If you extend this class with bike then you can call the borrowable methods without having to write the code over again.

Comment: I also suggested this approach but apparently it's not OO enough?

Comment: Too bad I can't talk to your teacher. This is what OOP is all about.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `interface`:

```
interface Item{
    boolean isBorrowed();
}
```

Then make `abstract` classes for all different items by implementing the `interface`.

```
abstract class Bike implements Item{
    //code
}

abstract class RollerSkates implements Item{
    //code
}

//etc.
```

Now `extend` these `abstract` classes:

```
public class BorrowedBike extends Bike{
    //code
    //add additional field 'due date'
    boolean isBorrowed(){
        return true;
    }
}

public class ReturnedBike extends Bike{
    //code
   //add additional field 'location'
    boolean isBorrowed(){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a very clear way to implement this but unfortunately the objective was to avoid having sub-classes for every type of item. I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @Kuririn Can you post the code you've written and the exact response from your teacher?  This is a relatively decent OO approach, but your teacher may have something else in mind (maybe generics, enums, Strings, etc.).  It is also possible your teacher isn't explaining to you what he/she wants in a well manner.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is to create a class type for each item , 
create Item class which is a generic class , and inherit from it 2 sub-classes borrowed item and returned one

```
class Bike
...
class Skates
...
class Roller

class Item<T>
...
class BorrowedItem<T> extends Item<T>
...
class ReturnedItem<T> extends Item<T>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making `borrowed bike` and `returned bike` for bike sub class 
you can follow an approach to make a class 
`item` with variable `nameOfItem` and `type` it can be either bike ,roller stakes or any other.
It will hold for an instance

```
Name            status
bike            returned
roller stakes   borrowed
```